# How to show categories in left sidebar in accordion view?

Tags: menu, category-products, sidebar

I am totally new and this is the first time when I have used Magento.

I have a theme http://ultimo.infortis-themes.com/demo/default/ and I want to add the sidebar on both sides of banners. Left sidebar will have categories in accordion view something like this http://www.amazon.com/home-automation-smarthome/b?ie=UTF8&node=6563140011 . and right sidebar will be static.
So my main problem is left sidebar and I am unable to find out that how can I show the categories in the left sidebar and in accordion view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is issue is fixed with custom code in theme. We have tried some code changes in theme and rendered the MENU and with the help of CSS got the exact what i want.

Comment: can you please share what you have modified

Answer (score 3):

Open this url once, you will get the solution.

http://tejabhagavan.blogspot.in/2016/01/accordion-tabs-in-magento-for-layered.html

Open a path as follows:

```
app/design/frontend/default/{your folder}/template/catelog/layer/view.phtml
```

Then open that that file & paste the following jquery script at the end of the page:

```
<script>var $j= jQuery.noConflict();// no conflict method
$j (document).ready(function(){
$j("#narrow-by-list > dt").click(function(){
if(false == $j(this).next().is(':visible')) {
$j('#narrow-by-list dd').slideUp(300);
}
$j(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
$j('#narrow-by-list dd').hide();
$j('#narrow-by-list dd:eq(0)').show();
});
</script>
```

**NOTE:**

#narrow-by-list is the id used in that file( ).
 If you used different id’s, replace this with your id and save the 
file. Refresh the cache and reload the browser to see the results. Use 
no-conflict method in magento. It is a good practice to avoid javascript
 conflicts in the page.